# Reducing nested loop complexity with help of Dictionary (or other data structure) in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, time-complexity, nested-loops

I am interested in reducing the time complexity for this code below with help of dictionary (or possibly another data structure).

As far as I understand my brute force solution has time complexity of `O(n^2)`, however, possibly could be done in `O(n)` (in n-times of non-nested loop).

The task is to print for for each day and location, the percentage of observations on that day and location that are mammal observations.

```
foreach (var day in EachDay(GetDateTimeForFirstObservation(animalObservations),
GetDateTimeForLastObservation(animalObservations)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Day: {0}", day.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

    foreach (var location in EachLocation(animalObservations
        .Where(ao => ao.Datetime.Day == day.Day).ToList()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Location: {0}", location);

        numOfAllAnimalsInLocationAndDay = animalObservations
            .Where(aob => aob.Location == location &&
                aob.Datetime.Date == day).Count();

        numOfMammalsAnimalsInLocationAndDay = animalObservations
            .Where(aob => aob.Location == location &&
            aob.Datetime.Date == day && aob.Animal.IsMammal).Count();

        Console.WriteLine("Percentage of Mammals in location and day: {0:N2}%",
            numOfMammalsAnimalsInLocationAndDay/numOfAllAnimalsInLocationAndDay * 100);
    }
}
```

Input looks something like this:

```
[
{"DateTime":"2020-02-22 10:10:15", "Location":"Backyard", "Animal": {"Species":"Camel", "IsMammal": "TRUE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-22 11:10:15", "Location":"Backyard", "Animal": {"Species":"Camel", "IsMammal": "TRUE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-22 12:10:15", "Location":"Backyard", "Animal": {"Species":"Ant", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-22 22:10:15", "Location":"Sky", "Animal": {"Species":"Flamingo", "IsMammal": "TRUE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-22 23:10:15", "Location":"Sky", "Animal": {"Species":"Bee", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-23 13:11:15", "Location":"City", "Animal": {"Species":"Racoon", "IsMammal": "TRUE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-24 15:10:00", "Location":"City", "Animal": {"Species":"Dog", "IsMammal": "TRUE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-24 19:10:00", "Location":"City", "Animal": {"Species":"Fly", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-24 19:10:15", "Location":"City", "Animal": {"Species":"Butterfly", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-24 19:10:20", "Location":"City", "Animal": {"Species":"Cat", "IsMammal": "TRUE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-24 19:10:30", "Location":"City", "Animal": {"Species":"Flee", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-25 21:10:15", "Location":"Village", "Animal": {"Species":"Horse", "IsMammal": "TRUE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-25 22:10:15", "Location":"Village", "Animal": {"Species":"Fly", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-25 23:10:15", "Location":"Village", "Animal": {"Species":"Bee", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}},
{"DateTime":"2020-02-25 10:10:15", "Location":"Home", "Animal": {"Species":"Iguana", "IsMammal": "FALSE"}}
]
```

And desired output:

```
Day: 22.02.2020
Location: Backyard
Percentage of Mammals in location and day: 66,67%
Location: Sky
Percentage of Mammals in location and day: 50,00%
Day: 23.02.2020
Location: City
Percentage of Mammals in location and day: 100,00%
Day: 24.02.2020
Location: City
Percentage of Mammals in location and day: 40,00%
Day: 25.02.2020
Location: Village
Percentage of Mammals in location and day: 33,33%
Location: Home
Percentage of Mammals in location and day: 0,00%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a **Dictionary**, with a key type including the day and location and a value type holding the mammal/non-mammal counts.

Try the code below. You will need to point the string constant near the top to the location of the JSON file. You will also need to add the NewtonSoft JSON library to your project. Note that I've overridden the Equals and GetHashCode methods in the class used as the dictionary's key type.

```
namespace Mammals
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;

    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string filePath = "C:\\temp\\mammals.json";

            // Read input from JSON:
            string jsonInput;
            using (var file = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)))
            {
                jsonInput = file.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var json = JArray.Parse(jsonInput);
            var sightings = json.Select(j => j.ToObject<Sighting>());

            // Set up dictionary, using day/location as key:
            var sightingDictionary = new Dictionary<SightingDayAndPlace, SightingCounter>();

            // Loop through sightings in O(n):
            foreach (var sighting in sightings)
            {
                var sightingTimeAndPlace = sighting.GetSightingDayAndPlace;
                if (!sightingDictionary.ContainsKey(sightingTimeAndPlace))
                {
                    sightingDictionary.Add(sightingTimeAndPlace, new SightingCounter());
                }

                if (sighting.IsMammal)
                {
                    sightingDictionary[sightingTimeAndPlace].MammalCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    sightingDictionary[sightingTimeAndPlace].NonMammalCount++;
                }
            }

            // Print output:
            var currentDay = default(DateTime);
            foreach (var item in sightingDictionary)
            {
                var key = item.Key;
                if (key.Day != currentDay)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Day: {key.Day:dd.MM.yyyy}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Location: {key.Location}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Percentage of Mammals in location and day: {item.Value.MammalPercentage:F}%");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private class SightingDayAndPlace
        {
            public SightingDayAndPlace(DateTime day, string location)
            {
                this.Day = day;
                this.Location = location;
            }

            public DateTime Day { get; }

            public string Location { get; }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj == null || !(obj is SightingDayAndPlace that))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return this.Day == that.Day
                       && this.Location == that.Location;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                // Consider a different implementation if memory or performance is relevant.
                return new { this.Day, this.Location }.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        private class Sighting
        {
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public Animal Animal { get; set; }
            public string Species => Animal.Species;
            public bool IsMammal => Animal.IsMammal;
            public DateTime Day => DateTime.Date;

            public SightingDayAndPlace GetSightingDayAndPlace => new SightingDayAndPlace(this.Day, this.Location);
        }

        private class Animal
        {
            public string Species { get; set; }
            public bool IsMammal { get; set; }
        }

        private class SightingCounter
        {
            public int MammalCount { get; set; }
            public int NonMammalCount { get; set; }

            public double MammalPercentage => (MammalCount / ((double)MammalCount + NonMammalCount)) * 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! It is clear, self contained and I appreciate effort of writing it the TDD with small, easily testable methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of really insane tricks to reduce time complexity but most of the time working with data you have to rely on how data ordered initialy. If it's not ordered that we can order it by some composite key. In your case the key is `Tuple<DateTime, Location>` where Item1 is day of date and Item2 is location. That would take n*log(n), and then use linear time to walk through the data producing results using linear time.

So looking at your data its already sorted. So we can skip that part and just walk through. Basic idea we initialize some state and chek if it changes we produce result. In our case state is current day, current location, and we track information in two variables total animals, total mammals.

```
    public static void PrintPopulation(List<AnimalObservations> animalObservations)
    {
        if (animalObservations.Count == 0)
            return;
        var item = animalObservations[0];
        string currentLocation = item.Location;
        DateTime currentDate = item.DateTime.Date;
        int totalAnimals = 1;
        int totalMammals = item.Animal.IsMammal ? 1 : 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < animalObservations.Count; i++)
        {
            item = animalObservations[i];
            if (currentLocation != item.Location ||
                currentDate != item.DateTime.Date)
            {
                PrintResult(currentDate, currentLocation, totalAnimals, totalMammals);
                totalMammals = 0;
                totalAnimals = 0;
                currentLocation = item.Location;
                currentDate = item.DateTime.Date;
            }

            totalAnimals++;
            totalMammals += item.Animal.IsMammal ? 1 : 0;
        }
        PrintResult(currentDate, currentLocation, totalAnimals, totalMammals);
    }

    public static void PrintResult(DateTime date, string location, int totalAnimals, int totalMammals)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{date} {location} {(double) totalMammals / totalAnimals}");
    }
```

I assume that

```
public class AnimalObservations
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public bool IsMammal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This assumes not only that the data is chronological but also that locations are never re-visited. The OP will know for sure but this doesn't seem likely, even though it's true of the small sample dataset.

Comment: @NeilT it seems likely look at the last record at  2020-02-25

Comment: Looking at the rest of the data, I suspect that's a typo for "2020-02-26"! But of course if we can assume pre-sorting then yes, this is a much simpler problem.

Comment: it's not a typo since there should be additional result in his output. but yeah I also thought solving it using dictionary initialy

Comment: @Irdis thank you for this good solution! It is nice that you gave a valuable info on approach of sorting and later on how to use state to look for a change. I would have accepted this if NeilT would not post the latter answer including the consideration for the unsorted data.

Comment: @NeilT please see comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution actually a complexity of `O(n^3)` because you're making 3 nested iterations:

1. Each distinct day
2. Each distinct location for the current day
3. Count number of animals and mammals for the day-location pair --- this you gave in a Linq expression, so is not so evident

Given that you have the following class structure:

```
public class AnimalObservation {
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
}

public class Animal {
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public bool IsMammal { get; set; }
}
```

You can do this in `O(n)` by using two dictionaries --- one for animals and one for mammals --- that have a day-location pair as a key and a counter as a value

```
    IDictionary<ValueTuple<DateTime, string>, int> animals = new Dictionary<ValueTuple<DateTime, string>, int>(new DayLocationComparer());
    IDictionary<ValueTuple<DateTime, string>, int> mammals = new Dictionary<ValueTuple<DateTime, string>, int>(new DayLocationComparer());
    foreach (AnimalObservation ao in aos) {
        ValueTuple<DateTime, string> dayLocation = new ValueTuple<DateTime, string>(ao.DateTime, ao.Location);

        if (!animals.ContainsKey(dayLocation)) {
            animals.Add(dayLocation, 1);
        } else {
            animals[dayLocation] = animals[dayLocation] + 1;
        }


        if (!mammals.ContainsKey(dayLocation) && ao.Animal.IsMammal) {
            mammals.Add(dayLocation, 1);
        } else if (!mammals.ContainsKey(dayLocation) && !ao.Animal.IsMammal) {
            mammals.Add(dayLocation, 0);
        } else if (mammals.ContainsKey(dayLocation) && ao.Animal.IsMammal) {
            animals[dayLocation] = animals[dayLocation] + 1;
        }
    }

    foreach (ValueTuple<DateTime, string> dayLocation in animals.Keys) {
        int nrOfAnimals = animals[dayLocation];
        int nrOfMammals = mammals[dayLocation];
        Console.WriteLine((double)nrOfMammals / nrOfAnimals * 100);
    }
```

Where `DayLocationComparer` is a comparer that ignores the Time part of the `DateTime`

```
public class DayLocationComparer : EqualityComparer<ValueTuple<DateTime, string>> {
    public override bool Equals(ValueTuple<DateTime, string> x, ValueTuple<DateTime, string> y) => x.Item1.Date == y.Item1.Date && x.Item2 == y.Item2;
    public override int GetHashCode(ValueTuple<DateTime, string> x) => x.Item1.GetHashCode();
}
```

Of course, I would recommend using maybe a class for the day-location pair for more readable code.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer. I did not test this - most probably this works just fine. For me this seems a bit complicated if I need to compare with the accepted answer. Though I liked that you use the EqualityComparer which is more generic and enforces GetHash and Equals override.